# MySQL procedure returning incorrect value to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have this stored procedure that inserts data into the event table. The problem is that the value returned to PHP in `select lastNum;` is 1 lower (inserted as 2 but will return 1) than when it is used in the previous insert statement. This doesn't make any sense to me as the value is not changed in between the 2 lines.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `insertEvent`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insertEvent`(ptitle varchar(500), pdescription varchar(500), pxcoord int(4), pycoord int(4), ptype char(1), pnumber int(11))
begin
 declare numExists int(1);
 declare lastNum int(9);


 select count(*) from event where `number`=pnumber;

 select insAndIncEventId() into lastNum from dual; 

 if numExists > 0 then
  update event set `number`=`number`+1 where `number`>=pnumber;
 end if;


 insert into event (id, title, description, xcoord, ycoord, `type`, `number`) values  (lastNum, ptitle, pdescription, pxcoord, pycoord, ptype, pnumber);

 select lastNum;

end$$


drop function if exists `insAndIncEventId`$$

create function `insAndIncEventId`() returns int(9)
begin
 declare event_id int(9);

 select nextId into event_id from eventid;

 update eventid set nextid=nextid+1;

 return event_id;

end$$
```

The PHP is as follows:

```
$eventid=$eventidstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
fb("event id count from sql:".count($eventid));
fb("event id from sql:".$eventid[0]);
```

Comment: What happens if it is inserted as 3, will it return as 2 or 1?

Comment: it was for counting the size of the array returned for debugging purposes. The number that I am using is retrieved in the next line.

Comment: What do you see if you use `print_r($eventid)`?

Comment: @S.Pols I just realized that `select count(*) from event where number=number` was the problem. I forgot to add `into numExists`, so the incorrect query was being returned. Thanks for the suggestion to use `print_r` as it helped me realize what the actual query being used was.

Comment: If your problem is solved, don't forget to publish the solution and mark the question as closed.